# Question about conformal equivalence from stein's complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

P is a polygonal region and F :D→P is a conformal map.

Lemma 4.4 Let z0 be a point on the unit circle. Then F(z) tends to a limit as z approaches z0 within the unit disc.

Proof. If not, there are two sequences {z1,z2,...} and {z1′,z2′,...}
in the unit disc that converge to z0 and are **so that F(zn) and F(zn′)
converge to two distinct points ζ and ζ′ in the closure of P**. Since F is conformal, the points ζ and ζ′ must lie on the boundary p of P. ...

My question is, why should F(zn) converge to some point in the closure of P when zn converges to z0? Since the closure of P is compact, I can find that there exists a convergent subsequence of F(zn). But I can't figure out the reason that F(zn) converges to some point.

Comment: @angryavian But to show that F(z) tends to a limit as z approaches z0 within the unit disc, I think we have to prove F(zn) converges to a limit for every sequence zn in the unit disc that converge to z0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lim_{z \to z_0} F(z)$ does not exist. We show that the following holds:

> ($*$) There exist two sequences $(z_n)$ and $(z'_n)$ each converging to $z_0$ such that $F(z_n) \to \zeta$ and $F(z'_n) \to \zeta'$ with $\zeta \ne \zeta'$.

Case 1: Suppose there exists a sequence $(u_n)$ converging to $z_0$, such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(u_n)$ does not exist. Since $P$ is compact, there is a subsequence $(z_n)$ such that $F(z_n)$ converges to some point $\zeta$. But because $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(u_n) \ne \zeta$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|F(u_n) - \zeta| > \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$. By focusing on such points, you can find a further subsequence $(z'_n)$ of $(u_n)$ such that $F(z'_n) \to \zeta'$ (where $|\zeta-\zeta'| \ge \epsilon$).

Case 2: Otherwise, for any sequence $(z_n)$ converging to $z_0$, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(z_n)$ exists. Then ($*$) must be true. (Otherwise, the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(z_n)$ is the same for any sequences $(z_n)$ converging to $z_0$, and therefore $\lim_{z \to z_0} F(z)$ exists, which contradicts our initial assumption.)

Comment: Thank you! It works!